# MVars are blocking indefinitely; but only in certain scenarios.

Tags: multithreading, haskell

First, because this is about a specific case, I haven't reduced the code at all, so it will be quite long, and in 2 parts (Helper module, and the main).

SpawnThreads in ConcurHelper takes a list of actions, forks them, and gets an MVar containing the result of the action. It them combines the results, and returns the resulting list. It works fine in certain cases, but blocks indefinitely on others.

If I give it a list of putStrLn actions, it executes them fine, then returns the resulting ()s (yes, I know running print commands on different threads at the same time is bad in most cases).

If I try running multiTest in Scanner though (which takes either scanPorts or scanAddresses, the scan range, and the number of threads to use; then splits the scan range over the threads, and passes the list of actions to SpawnThreads), it will block indefinitely. The odd thing is, according to the debug prompts scattered around ConcurHelper, on each thread, ForkIO is returning before the MVar is filled. This would make sense if it wasn't in a do block, but shouldn't the actions be performed sequentially? (I don't know if this is related to the problem or not; it's just something I noticed while attempting to debug it).

I've thought it out step by step, and if it's executing in the order laid out in spawnThreads, the following should happen:

- An empty MVar should be created inside forkIOReturnMVar, and passed to mVarWrapAct.
- mVarWrapAct should execute the action, and put the result in the MVar (this is where the problem seems to lie. "MVar filled" is never shown, suggesting the MVar is never put into)
- getResults should then take from the resulting list of MVars, and return the results

If point #2 isn't the issue, I can see where the problem would be (and if it is the issue, I can't see why putMVar never executes. Inside the scanner module, the only real function of interest for this question is multiTest. I only included the rest so it could be run).

To do a simple test, you can run the following:

- `spawnThreads [putStrLn "Hello", putStrLn "World"]` (should return [(),()])
- `multiTest (scanPorts "127.0.0.1") 1 (0,5)` (Creates the MVar, hangs for a sec, then crashes with the aforementioned error)

Any help in understanding whats going on here would be appreciated. I can't see what the difference between the 2 use cases are.

Thank you

(And I'm using this atrocious exception handling system because IO errors don't give codes for specific network exceptions, so I've been left with parsing messages to find out what happened)

Main:

```
module Scanner where

import Network
import Network.Socket
import System.IO
import Control.Exception
import Control.Concurrent
import ConcurHelper
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Char
import NetHelp

data NetException = NetNoException | NetTimeOut | NetRefused | NetHostUnreach
                    | NetANotAvail | NetAccessDenied | NetAddrInUse
    deriving (Show, Eq)

diffExcept :: Either SomeException Handle -> Either NetException Handle
diffExcept (Right h) = Right h
diffExcept (Left (SomeException m))
    | err == "WSAETIMEDOUT" = Left NetTimeOut
    | err == "WSAECONNREFUSED" = Left NetRefused
    | err == "WSAEHOSTUNREACH" = Left NetHostUnreach
    | err == "WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL" = Left NetANotAvail
    | err == "WSAEACCESS" = Left NetAccessDenied
    | err == "WSAEADDRINUSE" = Left NetAddrInUse
    | otherwise = error $ show m
    where
        err = reverse . dropWhile (== ')') . reverse . dropWhile (/='W') $ show m

extJust :: Maybe a -> a 
extJust (Just a) = a

selectJusts :: IO [Maybe a] -> IO [a]
selectJusts mayActs = do
    mays <- mayActs; return . map extJust $ filter isJust mays

scanAddresses :: Int -> Int -> Int -> IO [String]
scanAddresses port minAddr maxAddr =
    selectJusts $ mapM (\addr -> do
        let sAddr = "192.168.1." ++ show addr
        print $ "Trying " ++ sAddr ++ " " ++ show port
        connection <- testConn sAddr port
        if isJust connection
            then do hClose $ extJust connection; return $ Just sAddr
        else return Nothing) [minAddr..maxAddr]

scanPorts :: String -> Int -> Int -> IO [Int]
scanPorts addr minPort maxPort =
    selectJusts $ mapM (\port -> do
        --print $ "Trying " ++ addr ++ " " ++ show port
        connection <- testConn addr port
        if isJust connection
            then do hClose $ extJust connection; return $ Just port
        else return Nothing) [minPort..maxPort]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    withSocketsDo $ do
        putStrLn "Scan Addresses or Ports? (a/p)"
        choice <- getLine
        if (toLower $ head choice) == 'a'
            then do
                putStrLn "On what port?"
                sPort <- getLine
                addrs <- scanAddresses (read sPort :: Int) 0 255
                print addrs
        else do
            putStrLn "At what address?"
            address <- getLine
            ports <- scanPorts address 0 9999
            print ports
        main

testConn :: HostName -> Int -> IO (Maybe Handle)
testConn host port = do
    result <- try $ timedConnect 1 host port

    let result' = diffExcept result
    case result' of
        Left e -> do putStrLn $ "\t" ++ show e; return Nothing
        Right h -> return $ Just h

setPort :: AddrInfo -> Int -> AddrInfo
setPort addInf nPort = case addrAddress addInf of
                (SockAddrInet _ host) -> addInf { addrAddress = (SockAddrInet (fromIntegral nPort) host)}

getHostAddress :: HostName -> Int -> IO SockAddr
getHostAddress host port = do
    addrs <- getAddrInfo Nothing (Just host) Nothing
    let adInfo = head addrs
        newAdInfo = setPort adInfo port
    return $ addrAddress newAdInfo

timedConnect :: Int -> HostName -> Int -> IO Handle
timedConnect time host port = do
    s <- socket AF_INET Stream defaultProtocol
    setSocketOption s RecvTimeOut time; setSocketOption s SendTimeOut time
    addr <- getHostAddress host port
    connect s addr
    socketToHandle s ReadWriteMode

multiTest :: (Int -> Int -> IO a) -> Int -> (Int, Int) -> IO [a]
multiTest partAction threads (mi,ma) = 
    spawnThreads $ recDiv [mi,perThread..ma]
    where
        perThread = ((ma - mi) `div` threads) + 1
        recDiv [] = []
        recDiv (curN:restN) =
            partAction (curN + 1) (head restN) : recDiv restN
```

Helper:

```
module ConcurHelper where

import Control.Concurrent
import System.IO

spawnThreads :: [IO a] -> IO [a]
spawnThreads actions = do
    ms <- mapM (\act -> do m <- forkIOReturnMVar act; return m) actions
    results <- getResults ms
    return results

forkIOReturnMVar :: IO a -> IO (MVar a)
forkIOReturnMVar act = do
    m <- newEmptyMVar
    putStrLn "Created MVar"
    forkIO $ mVarWrapAct act m
    putStrLn "Fork returned"
    return m

mVarWrapAct :: IO a -> MVar a -> IO ()
mVarWrapAct act m = do a <- act; putMVar m a; putStrLn "MVar filled"

getResults :: [MVar a] -> IO [a]
getResults mvars = do
    unpacked <- mapM (\m -> do r <- takeMVar m; return r) mvars
    putStrLn "MVar taken from"
    return unpacked
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `forkIOReturnMVar` isn't exception safe: whenever `act` throws, the `MVar` isn't going to be filled.

#### Minimal example

```
import ConcurHelper

main = spawnThreads [badOperation]
  where badOperation = do
            error "You're never going to put something in the MVar"
            return True
```

As you can see, `badOperation` throws, and therefore the `MVar` won't get filled in `mVarWrapAct`.

#### Fix

Fill the `MVar` with an appropriate value if you encounter an exception. Since you cannot provide a default value for all possible types `a`, it's better to use `MVar (Maybe a)` or `MVar (Either b a)` as you already do in your network code.

In order to catch the exceptions, use one of the operations provided in [`Control.Exception`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Exception.html). For example, you could use `onException`:

```
mVarWrapAct :: IO a -> MVar (Maybe a) -> IO ()
mVarWrapAct act m = do 
  onException (act >>= putMVar m . Just) (putMVar m Nothing)
  putStrLn "MVar filled"
```

However, you might want to preserve the actual exception for more information. In this case you could simply use `catch` together with `Either SomeException a` :

```
mVarWrapAct :: IO a -> MVar (Either SomeException a) -> IO ()
mVarWrapAct act m = do 
  catch (act  >>= putMVar m . Right) (putMVar m . Left)
  putStrLn "MVar filled"
```

Comment: Rethought it over, and the action (in this case scanPorts) has its own exception handling via testConn; which returns a maybe. An error occurring in that action should never affect mVarWrapAct because it's handled internally.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Except if you call `error`. Have you verified that you _never_ go into `otherwise = error $ show m`?

Comment: Fair point. Didn't think of that. Wouldn't it then display the thrown error though instead of the blocked indefinitely error?

Comment: I don't think that an unidentified error being thrown is the issue. I changed the `otherwise = error` line to map to a TimeOut exception, and it still happens. 2 other interesting things are, it happens at the completion of the action and not during, and if I run it with 2 threads, 1 of the threads will complete, but the other fails. Edit: I looked at it closer, and it looks like for some reason, one of the threads never starts. They both output their errors as they happen, and only 1 of the threads outputs anything.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: What I'm currently curious about is whether you tried the fix and you still encounter the `MVar timed out`behaviour. Does this still happen with the fix?

Comment: I was reluctant to try it immediately because I'm currently at work, and I didn't want to change that only to have it not work, given I'll have to change the dependent functions to deal with Maybes, and I'm short on time to play around with it. I thought going more to the root (error being thrown mid execution) would be an easier way to tell. When I get off (5 hours), I'll try it. I also noticed that one of the threads never returns, despite not throwing any uncaught errors.

Comment: It did appear to fix it. I'm confused now though. Why did a catch-all not solve this? Why did the error itself not show, and instead the MVar error? Regardless, thank you for your patience.